# C# OleDbDataAdaper apply UPDATE

Tags: c#, sql, oledbdataadapter

I have built a function that should UPDATE a table using a OleDbDataAdaper, but I am getting this error when the parser reaches the adapter:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here is my code, and I think that I am missing some code that would actually make the update...

```
if (dataset2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DataTable datatable2 = dataset2.Tables[0];                      
    foreach (DataRow datarow2 in datatable2.Rows)                   
    {
        conexiuneBD.Open();                                         
        string id = Convert.ToString(datarow2["ID"]);
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter3 = new OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE table SET occupied='True',date=? WHERE ID=?", DBConnection);
        adapter3.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", date);
        adapter3.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", id);
        conexiuneBD.Close();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Separate issue from the question, but you never call `adapter3.Update();`

Comment: Also: which line _exactly_ does that error occur? The line with the constructor, or the first line after?

Comment: @HassanNisar `?` is appropriate for OleDbCommand since it doesn't support named parameters.

Comment: Finally, it looks like you're looping through one db result set to update one record at a time based on the results. This is almost always the wrong way to do this. Post how you fill `dataset2`, and we can probably help you get that hold thing down to one single update query.

Comment: The break will interrupt the foreach.Thanks for letting me know about the .Update() .  The error occurs on the constructor line.

Comment: Strange that it happens on the constructor line. There's nothing there that could possibly be `null`, except DBConnection, and if it were `null` I'd expect there error to happen later.

Comment: What value you have provided to `date` variable?

Comment: the "date" field of the database is Date/Time (acces database) in the "6/29/2014" format while the variable is a string with the same format

Comment: i tried different configurations with the data transmited in the update but it gives out the same error

Comment: Missing `Update()` code could not be actual cause `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` Please clarify how you populate dataset? Where you initialized `conexiuneBD`? What is `DBConnection` etc.

Comment: I have fixed it by using a different approach.